# Disable ADD PDF media button on rich text editor

Tags: pages, wp-admin, dashboard, editor

I'm looking for a way to completely disable **"add pdf**" media button on text editor but not with css tricks. Is it a hook to add on function.php for doing this?

Also a need to keep **add media** button.

Thanks for your answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a core WordPress button so it must be added by a plugin.

You can upload a PDF with the add media button anyway, so look for the plugin that's adding it and disable it.